# Are there any problems after glibc update from 1.2.10 to 2.12 in Linux?

Tags: upgrade, dependencies, glibc

I want to update my glibc from 1.2.10 to 2.12. Are there any problems regarding dependency for other tools and software currently installed using previous version of glibc on CentOS release 6.3 (Final) with kernel 2.6.32-279.9.1.el6.x86_64?

Comment: I think you may not be looking at libc. Your CentOS system does not run glibc 1.2, at least not as the base libc. CentOS 2.1 already had been on glibc 2.2.4. Are you sure it's glibc?

Comment: yes I am damm sure I use
glib-config --version 
1.2.10

Comment: I see, please update your question. `glib-config` relates to GLib, which is part of gnome. Your question asked glibc (and the answer below is regarding to glibc). I know it's confusing, but they are two very very different library packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely. The rest of the system must be upgraded along with it. Otherwise a whole lot of binaries will cease to run because they are linked against a different version of Glibc.

In cases where the upgrade is minor, this tends not to be an issue.

---

If you name your distro an version, people might give you more specific answers.

Comment: I am running on CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
with kernel 2.6.32-279.9.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: BTW: user is asking about GLib, not glibc. I'd have called this out in my above comment, but I have no idea how to type Cyrillic on my keyboard :)